# How to add files to zip even when part of exclude pattern

Tags: linux, unix, zip

Regarding zip, I'm looking for a way to ensure a file is added to an archive independent of what has been passed to the archive creation exclusion list.

In my instance, I've developed an application that allows users to specify their own exclusion filter when creating a zip.

However, I need to ensure a couple custom files are always added to the archive, independent of what was specified in the filter.

For example:

- Filters Specified: "*.bar"
- File I need to add: foo.bar

So if I execute

```
zip -rq -i foo.bar -x "*.bar"
```

foo.bar will not be included in the archive.

So it comes down to:

- How can one override what is in the exclusion list for the few files I need added?
- Alternatively, could one develop an exclusion expression that combines what the user specified something that effectively says omit it all but foo.bar?

A solution I've come up with is to take two passes at it - first create an archive with the exclusion list and then grow the archive by foo.bar, but I'm looking for a way to do it in a single shot.

Thanks

Comment: The easiest method to achieve this is run first the ZIP compression with the user defined exclusion list and then run the ZIP compression again with adding to already created ZIP file the files which must be always added to the archive with the options necessary to skip files already present in the archive file. In best case no files are added to the ZIP file on second execution, in worst case all "always to add" files are added on second execution.

Comment: Thanks Mofi.  I'm actually doing this right now, however it comes with a downside - an entirely new archive is generated while the existing one is retained, at least temporarily. This can present problems with disk space.  That being said, one way around the double creation is to set compression to 'store' rather than compress (the '-0' switch) and you can add files after the fact without incurring the penalty of building an entirely new archive.

Answer (score 1):

The **`-i`** option is used to **include only** the specified files. With pattern "foo.bar" we only include the file named foo.bar leaving others.

The **`-x`** option is used to **exclude files**. With pattern `*.bar` we exclude the `foo.bar` file that we included before.

Also you must consider that the patterns will be resolved as [pathname expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) not as POSIX or Perl regular expresion. If you want do patterns more complex you can use [extended patterns](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language).

By example:

```
shopt -s extglob
zip -rq foo.zip . -i ?(foo.bar|!(*.bar))
shopt -u extglob
```

Or:

```
shopt -s extglob
zip -rq foo.zip . -x !(!(*.bar)|foo.bar)
shopt -u extglob
```

But the last commands aren't recursive because the patterns doesn't contemplate subdirectories. Although we use `-r` option we include only the files in pattern. The manual page tell us about write `\` before of `*` for apply recursively, but not work with all patterns.

Also you can use other commands to get list of files to include.

By example:

```
zip -rq foo.zip . -i `find ./ -not -name "*.bar" -o -name "foo.bar"`
```

Or:

```
zip -r foo.zip . -x `find ./ -name "*.bar" -a -not -name "foo.bar"`
```